# Mover toda la vista al abrir el teclado

Tags: java, android, scroll, vistas, manifest

Tengo mi activityMain en donde tengo un login sencillo, en este al abrir el teclado para ingresar los datos se superpone el teclado sobre el campo de password y no deja hacer scroll por lo que estuve viendo como solucionarlo pero ahroa se mueve nada mas lo que queda debajo del teclado y se pone encima de la demás vista y se ve mal, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o hay alguna otra manera.

**Así se ve normal sin abrir el teclado**

[image: Vista principal]

**Así se veía antes de hacer los cambios, el teclado se superpone a los componentes**

[image: Sin corrección]

**Así se ve con los cambios**

[image: Con las correcciones]

> Lo que hice fue colocar dos lineas de código que teoría iban a funcionar

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ValetParking">
        <activity android:name=".login.ChangePasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.ForgotPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.LocationActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.AboutThePlaceActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".login.CreateAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TabLayoutOperatorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".TabLayoutAdministratorActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Operator.CloseTicket" />
        <activity android:name=".Operator.ProfileOperatorActivity" />

    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <!-- Google maps -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="------------------------------------" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Background -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        style="@style/background" />

    <!-- Background title -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/background_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="133dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_title" />

    <!-- Title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/login_title" />

    <!-- Title icon -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/title_icon"
        android:layout_width="155dp"
        android:layout_height="104dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/background_title"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/title_icon" />

    <!-- Title info -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_info"
        style="@style/message"
        android:layout_below="@id/title_icon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:text="@string/login_info_title"
        android:clickable="true"/>


    <!-- Username -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_username"
        style="@style/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/create_account_username"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_person">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_username_edit"
            style="@style/text_input_edit_text"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Password -->
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_password"
        style="@style/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_username"
        android:hint="@string/create_account_password"
        app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/ic_lock">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/login_password_edit"
            style="@style/text_input_edit_text"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Remember me -->
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remember_me_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
        android:buttonTint="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/remember_me_checkbox_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/remember_me_checkbox"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/remember_me" />

    <!-- Forgot password -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgot_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/login_password"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            style="@style/button"
            android:text="@string/button_login" />

        <!-- Create account -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/create_account"
            style="@style/message"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="@string/login_create_account" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Agrega más código, no veo ahí los edittexts, ni el botón ni nada

Comment: Buenas amigo! Ya lo he agregado

Comment: Si te hago un diseño nuevo usando LinearLayout en ves de de RelativeLayout, lo usarías si resuelve tu problema? o prefieres usar RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te hice un diseño nuevo y es adaptativo [MARCALA COMO RESPONDIDA SI TE SIRVE]

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="VALET PARKING"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Inicie sesion y maneje sus autos y bla bla blablabla"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="correo"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck"/>


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/etPasswordLayout1"
        card_view:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            card_view:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:hint="password"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:paddingStart="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck,SpeakableTextPresentCheck"/>


    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:text="Recordarme"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/Verde"
        android:textColorLink="@color/Verde"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reset_pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Olvidaste tu pass?"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="iniciar sesion"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Crear cuenta"
        android:textColor="@color/Negro"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
      </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si funciona, muchísimas gracias, voy a analizar el código para comprenderlo mejor y saberlo aplicar

Answer (score 0):

debes utilizar "adjustPan" el adjustResize no siempre funciona, salvo que tengas trabajado los temas asociados a distintos tama;os...
ver el siguiente https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=es-419#wsoft

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/389214)